# In Excel 2016, how can I ensure a busy application correctly ignores/rejects requests to handle new spreadsheets or open files

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop, excel-2016

Having moved to Excel 2016, we've encountered an issue where attempting to open a new Excel instance from the start menu, the command line, or the jump list now ends up doing nothing whilst our VSTO addin is doing work in tasks and blocking (with message pumping) on the main thread. It looks like the new Excel instance realises there's an existing one and tries to get it to handle the request instead.

What I'd like to happen, of course, is for the new Excel instance to open transparently.

Please note that whilst Tasks are executing within the addin, they use a `DispatcherFrame` to ensure message pumping takes place, and there aren't any annoying messages of the sort `This window is waiting for an OLE action to complete` or breaks when debugging because the window hasn't responded for 30s or so. I believe removing this *might* help, but it would also cause other issues, so I'm reluctant to go there.

Approaches attempted:

- Turning on `Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests` (no impact)
- SubClassing `Application.hWnd` with a custom `delegate int Win32WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);` via `IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, Win32WndProc newProc)` (no messages are actually received)

What I haven't tried (and don't know whether to) are

- Trying to find out if Excel implements a WCF server in Office 2016 and intercepting messages to it
- Temporarily removing a reference to the application from the ROT (Running object table), or otherwise doing anything directly to the ROT.
- Checking other hWnds underneath that reported by `Application` in case messages are being sent directly to them (not sure where to start)

Can anyone explain what's actually happening here, and how to avoid?

Comment: That is sounds pretty normal.  Excel is a single-instance app, way too fat to allow many instances to execute.  So the second instance talks to the first one and asks it to open a window or spreadsheet.  Unsubtle UI thread related stuff.  You must not interfere with that kind of heavy plumbing, anything that smells like DoEvents style busy-pumping is quite likely to do so.  Don't do it is the only good advice.  Task certainly doesn't require it, Excel doesn't, the entire point of a UI thread is that you can always teleport back to finish what you started.

Comment: The tasks are essentially preparation for large-scale automation of workbooks where the structure has been partially prepped in advance. They're there to grab data that's going to stored within the workbook, and typically take 2-10 mins to complete, longer if network latency is slow. We basically don't want users messing with the workbook during that time, but it's a lot longer than the warnings that amount to "why aren't you pumping messages?" take to show up. That'd be fine if it acted as earlier versions did as more of a multi-instance app. It's stopped doing so, hence the question...

Comment: NB of course, that if we could display a modal dialog with respect to a *specific* workbook, we could probably get away with trying to do a lot more work properly. I'm not aware of how to do that, though

Comment: You've been doing it wrong for, probably, a long time.  That does not obligate Microsoft to keep supporting doing it wrong.  Just google "0x800a03ec" or "excel error 1004" for the large number of very hard-to-fix crashes that are caused by re-entrancy problems.  If you need an earlier version to keep your code running then just put that as a requirement on the box.  If you want to fix it then you really do have to show what you are doing.  Or call Microsoft Support, surely worth the five-hundred bucks.  Always better when bad news comes from somebody you pay :)